# Bash: Variable Isn't Used / Defined Properly

Tags: bash, debian

working on my auto-install script. It isn't using my variable properly, debug log looks like this.

I've tried several variants, using "" instead of '', not using '' or "" but just $variable. The script looks like this:

```
echo "Creating Apache2 VHost and Wordpress blog $domain"

VAR1=$sitealias
VAR2=$domain
MOREF=$`pwgen 14 1`
echo $MOREF is SQL password.

mkdir /var/www/"$domain"
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/"$domain"
echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myblog.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress

    Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
    <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$domain.conf

mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword create wp_$sitealias
mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword CREATE USER     $sitealias@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MOREF';
mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON   wp_'$sitealias.'* TO '$sitealias'@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit
```

The script should insert the variable in the commands, folder directories. Instead the variable is just ignored, as is shown in the debug log.

UPDATE:

variable capturing works fine now. However, SQL doesn't like your double quote (copy and pasted them)

```
root@hosting:/bin# hello.sh letstest.tld testtesttdjsuqwu
Creating Apache2 VHost and Wordpress blog 
qui2AenaihoQu9 is SQL password.
mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'create wp_testtesttdjsuqwu'
mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'CREATE USER   'testtesttdjsuqwu'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'q'
mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_testtesttdjsuqwu.*  TO 'testtesttd'
/bin/hello.sh: line 37: FLUSH: command not found
/bin/hello.sh: line 38: quit: command not found
```

Comment: Are you sure that 'domain' is properly set ? What is the output of the script. Also consider running with '-u' (add 'set -u' before the first line) to identify undefined/misspelled variables.

Comment: Use `$( )` to run a command and capture its output instead of backticks (and if you do use backticks, don't put a dollar sign in front of them). Also, put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `echo "$MOREF is SQL password."). There are some places it's safe to leave them off (like the right side of an assignment, except for sometimes), but it's generally safer to just use them. Finally, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variables for your own things, because there are a bunch of all-caps variables with special functions, and re-using one of them by mistake can cause trouble.

Comment: Ok, one more note: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net). It won't spot everything, but it'll point out a lot of common mistakes.

Comment: Hello,

I added the complete code. Basically, it creates folders, files, and SQL commands. You say I should use $( ) to capture the output. But why does <code>MOREF=$`pwgen 14 1</code> return and show the result correctly when ran?

Comment: Also, how do I code the script so that I can set variables when running the application? Like so:

<code>root@hosting:/bin# hello.sh VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2

Comment: @PatrickPeyre Putting a dollar sign before a backtick is not valid shell syntax. According to the [POSIX spec (section 2.6)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06), "the result is unspecified". All the shells I tested it in treat the dollar sign as a literal character (so the value of `MOREF` starts with a dollar sign), but if that's what you want it would be better to single-quote or escape the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parameters inside your script (based on the comments above, 'domain' and 'sitealias') use the '$1' '$2' to capture them

```
domain=$1
sitealias=$2
# Fixed quoting of pwgen)
MOREF=$(pwgen 14 1)
# Rest of the script here, using $domain, $sitealias
echo $MOREF is SQL password.

mkdir /var/www/"$domain"
```

It's not completely clear what value do you want to 'APACHE_LOG_DIR'. Assuming that this variable need to be resolved at run-time, based on the Apache default value, you want to use single quote instead of double quote for the 'echo' statement. This will defer the resolution of this variable.

```
echo '<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myblog.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/wordpress

    # Lines removed for

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
' > /etc/apache2/sites-available/$domain.conf
```

Also, consider double-quoting for the mysqladmin setup command. Use double quote to enable variable substitution, Use single quote when needed by mysql.

```
mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword "create wp_$sitealias"
mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword "CREATE USER  '$sitealias'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MOREF'";
mysqladmin -u root password supersecretpassword "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_$sitealias.* TO '$sitealias'@'localhost';"
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit
```